# How to retrieve and decode a timestamp date property from authenticode signed files in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, timestamp, code-signing, authenticode

I recently found here a very informative article about getting various informations from Authenticode signed executables:

[Get timestamp from Authenticode Signed files in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net)

I managed how to retrieve TimeStamp date attribute but i don't know much about raw data conversion, and I assume it has to be done to convert that attribute from byte array to DateTime object.

Could anyone give me an example how to achive this in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-use the code from Mono's chktrust tool [1] which use Mono.Security.dll [2] to decode Authenticode signatures, including the timestamps. All the code is available under the MIT X.11 license.

[1] https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/tools/security/chktrust.cs

[2] https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/class/Mono.Security