# How to extract the date a C# manifest was signed

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to retrieve the **date that the manifest was signed** because I need to compare the date to the expiration date of a certificate.  the manifest signature tag seems to contain no timestamp in it.

I am using System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.SignedXml to load a manifest file. I'm unable to determine the method I need to use to extract the date the manifest was signed.

There is no plain text date in the manifest file itself so im assuming its embedded in the signaturevalue or other tag?

Am I taking the wrong approach to this?

Comment: Rolled comments in.  Good luck.

Comment: Try to get the timestamp using p/invoke as described in [this question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net/4927876#4927876

Comment: Isn't that just the same as the date the file was last modified?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert with this kind of thing, but you might be able to use [Mage.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acz3y3te.aspx) (Microsoft's command line Manifest Generation and Editing Tool) to read the timestamp from the manifest file. It comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

You might get some info from [the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.aspx).