# How to get information about digest algorithm from signed file?

Tags: .net, cryptography, digest

I have a file that I signed using singtool and a certificate. When using the signtool, you can specify digest algorithm (SHA1 is used by default). Now, is there a way in .net how can I find out which digest algorithm was used for signing a file? Using methods from cryptography namespace, I am able to get details about used certificate, but I have not found out how to get information about digest algorithm. Maybe I am totally wrong and it is not even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find managed solution, so I end up invoking some methods from crypt32.dll as described here [Get timestamp from Authenticode Signed files in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281057/get-timestamp-from-authenticode-signed-files-in-net)